# Querying Elasticsearch by combining a range and a term match json format

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am trying to query an Elasticsearch index by a time range, and additionally have a term match a specific string value.

I have tried this query, which seems pretty straightforward:

```
 {
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "method": "/customer/help"
          }
        },
        {
          "range" : {
            "startTime": {
              "from" : "2015-10-20T13:00-04:00",
              "to" : "2015-10-20T14:00-04:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, I want all of the documents within the given time range that also have a method value of `"/customer/help"`.

In my results, I am receiving results that are within the time range, but I am getting documents that have various values for the `"method"` field, when I just want results with `"/customer/help"` in that field.

Comment: Are the various values for "method" field values that have either "customer" or "help" along with results that have the expected "customer/help"?  In that case the problem is that Elasticsearch is analyzing the field (probably Standard analyzer if you have not specified the mapping).  If you don't expect to use the analyzer for that field in the future, then you can set "index" : "not_analyzed" property for that field.

Comment: The other values do have customer/<something else> but what is weird is that if I run a query separately where I am excluding the range, I only get results where the method = "customer/help".

Comment: What are you passing for the size param?  Is it just a coincidence and you are only seeing a subset of all results when you cut out the range query?

Comment: You should use a `term` query instead of `match` query if you're looking for exact matches for your `method` field.

Comment: Somebody visiting this post should also look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556729/how-to-have-range-and-match-query-in-one-elastic-search-query-using-python

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In your mapping you need to have `method` as `not_analyzed` (or analyzed with `keyword` analyzer) and the query should use `term`. In this way, the text you index in method is indexed as is as a single token and `term` makes sure the text you search matches exactly the token indexed in `method`:

```
    "method": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
```

And the query you need to use:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "method": "/customer/help"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "startTime": {
              "from": "2015-10-20T13:00-04:00",
              "to": "2015-10-20T14:00-04:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it turns out it was tokenizing that string therefore skewing the results. This answer is correct, and thanks! Also I thought it would be helpful to point out that using the "match_phrase" query instead of the "match" query achieved the correct results as well without changing the index.