# How to have Range and Match query in one elastic search query using python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch

I have to find the matching documents which have the string, for example: "sky", within some "key" range. When I write separate match and range query, I get the output from the ES but it throws an exception when merged together.

range query:

```
res = es.search(index="dummy",
                body={"from":0, "size":0,"query": {"range":{"key":{"gte":"1000"}}}})
```

match query:

```
res = es.search(index="dummy",
                body={"from":0, "size":0,"query": {"match":{"word":"sky"}}})
```

combined query:

```
res = es.search(index="dummy",
                body={
                  "from":0,
                  "size":0,
                  "query": {
                    "range":{
                      "key":{"gte":"1000"}
                    }
                  },
                  "match":{"word":"sky"}
                })
```

The combined query when executed throws the error:

> raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
>   elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [match].')

What is the correct way of merging both the queries?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to do it like this using a `bool/must` query

```
res = es.search(index="dummy", body={
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "key": {
              "gte": "1000"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "word": "sky"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```